# Node.JS JavaScript buffer to image conversion not a valid bitmap file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to transfer an image file data from one node.js script to another.

I read the image file in 'parameter.js' using 'readfilesync', then transfer it to another script 'convert.js'.

convert.js is meant to re-convert the file data back to an image using `WriteFile` - and it seems to do a good job.

However, when I try to open the newly created file, I get the error like;

`This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported.`

Could you help me spot the problem?

Thanks for your help!

`parameter.js`:

```js
// Path to image file
let datasetRoute = resolve('./app/scripts/myphotos/bubbles1.png');

// Get image file
let file = readDataset();

// Function to get image file
function readDataset() {

    try { 

        // Fetch dataset using new 'currentPage' number
        return fs.readFileSync(datasetRoute,  'utf8');
    }

    catch (err) { 
        return err;
    }
}

// Create parameter function
const parameterFunctions = {

    // Define function parameters
    
    // Parameter 1
    parameter1: file, // set parameter1 as value of file

}
```

`convert.js`:

```js
var bytes = params.uParams[0].parameter1.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");

fs.writeFileSync('app/scripts/media/test.png', bytes, 'base64', (err) => {
    if (!err) 
    console.log(`Image saved!`);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried reading your png as 'base64' instead of 'utf8' encoding?

Comment: Thanks! But already tried that.

Comment: If you only need to perform a copy you might as well do a simple 'binary' read and write

Comment: @DadiBit Thanks a lot! Binary worked! Ignore earlier comment. I had forgotten to apply 'binary' configuration on the read script. Thanks again!

Comment: @DadiBit Fixed code is below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted the entire operation into a simple read and write 'binary' format.

Finally worked!

Here's the code:

parameter.js:

```
// Path to image file
let datasetRoute = resolve('./app/scripts/myphotos/bubbles1.png');

// Get image file
let file = readDataset();

// Function to get image file
function readDataset() {

    try { 

        // Fetch dataset using new 'currentPage' number
        return fs.readFileSync(datasetRoute, 'binary');
    }

    catch (err) { 
        return err;
    }
}

// Create parameter function
const parameterFunctions = {

    // Define function parameters
    
    // Parameter 1
    parameter1: file, // set parameter1 as value of file

}
```

convert.js:

```
var bytes = params.uParams[0].parameter1;

fs.writeFileSync('app/scripts/media/test.png', bytes, 'binary', (err) => {
    if (!err) 
    console.log(`Image saved!`);
});
```

Comment: You can accept your answer in a few days, btw. This way it's marked as closed, and it can reach more people when googling similar stuff.